# how do I copy files specified in array to another folder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have folder "all" with many files. Inside it I put a batch file which I want to copy some files from "all" folder into "inner" folder. The files that I want to be copied I specify in array "files" inside batch file. What should batch file contain? This doesn't seem to be working:

```
set sources[0]="file1.txt"
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set sources[') do xcopy /s "path\to\source\%%s" "path\to\source\inner\%%s"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - There is a "problem" with quotes. You are quoting the file name AND the full path including the filename which is still quoted so you end with `"path\to\source\"file1.txt""`. It can work as is, but sometimes it can generate problem. Use proper quoting.

2 - `xcopy /s` is intended for recursive directory copying. Not single file copying.

Try

```
set "sources[0]=file1.txt"
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set sources[') do (
    copy "path\to\source\%%~s" "path\to\source\inner\%%~s"
)
```